# Disallow creating a class object with braces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Assigning to a variable of class with braces like { a: 1, b: 2 } does not cause a compile error.

```
@MyDecorator()
class Foo {
    public a: number = 0;
}

const foo1: Foo = { a: 1 }; // No Error
```

But foo1 is not decorated because it's not created with a constructor.
I want to force to create an object with new ClassName().

How to disallow creating an instance with { ... }?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript uses structural typing to determine  compatibility between types. If your class contains a just the field `a` then an object literal with that field will will be compatible with the class.

The simplest way to make sure your class is not compatible with an object literal is to add a private field, even if you don't use it.

```
class Foo {
    public a: number = 0;
    private no:undefined;
}

const foo1: Foo = { a: 1 } //error
```